# File encryption in c++ using openssl, decryption in java using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: java, c++, encryption, openssl, cryptography

Using openssl in a c++ project I performed file encryption using AES/CBC 128 bit. I have a java project which performs decryption of file.

Idea is, in c++, We will read the original file in chunk of 4096 bytes. Will perform encryption using openssl function `EVP_CipherUpdate()` once we receive encrypted buffer from this function, we will write IV (of 16 bytes) into the output file then the encrypted buffer and at last by calling `EVP_CipherFinal()` we will cipher the block (of 16 bytes) and write that into file. This logic will be called into a `while` loop until EOF is reached.

So, encrypted file will have 16 bytes (of IV) + 4096 or chunk size bytes(actual encrypted text) + 16 bytes (of padding). For every 4096 (and last remaining) bytes this structure follows in encrypted file.

Below is the function which performs file encryption in c++ using openssl: (Referenced from https://medium.com/@amit.kulkarni/encrypting-decrypting-a-file-using-openssl-evp-b26e0e4d28d4)

```
void file_encrypt_decrypt(cipher_params_t* params, FILE* ifp, FILE* ofp) {
    const size_t BUFSIZE = 4096;

    /* Allow enough space in output buffer for additional block */
    int cipher_block_size = EVP_CIPHER_block_size(params->cipher_type);

    unsigned char in_buf[BUFSIZE];
    OPENSSL_assert(cipher_block_size == 16);
    unsigned char out_buf[4096+16+16];

    int num_bytes_read, out_len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx;

    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n",
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CTX_NEW);
    }

    /* Don't set key or IV right away; we want to check lengths */
    if (!EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, params->cipher_type, NULL, NULL, NULL, params->encrypt)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CipherInit_ex failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n",
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CIPHER_INIT);
    }

    OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(ctx) == 16);
    OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(ctx) == 16);

    /* Now we can set key and IV */
    if (!EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, params->key, params->iv, params->encrypt)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CipherInit_ex failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n",
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CIPHER_INIT);
    }

    while(1) 
    {
        // Read in data in blocks until EOF. Update the ciphering with each read.
        num_bytes_read = fread(in_buf, sizeof(unsigned char), BUFSIZE, ifp);
        if (ferror(ifp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fread error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, errno);
        }
        if (!EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, out_buf, &out_len, in_buf, num_bytes_read)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CipherUpdate failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n",
                ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CIPHER_UPDATE);
        }

        fwrite(params->iv, sizeof(unsigned char), EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(ctx), ofp);
        fflush(ofp);
        if (ferror(ofp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fwrite error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, errno);
        }

        fwrite(out_buf, sizeof(unsigned char), out_len, ofp);
        fflush(ofp);
        if (ferror(ofp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fwrite error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, errno);
        }

        /* Now cipher the final block and write it out to file */
        if (!EVP_CipherFinal(ctx, out_buf, &out_len)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: EVP_CipherFinal_ex failed. OpenSSL error: %s\n",
                ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, ERR_EVP_CIPHER_FINAL);
        }

        fwrite(out_buf, sizeof(unsigned char), out_len, ofp);
        fflush(ofp);

        if (ferror(ofp)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fwrite error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            //cleanup(params, ifp, ofp, errno);
        }
        if (num_bytes_read < BUFSIZE) {
            /* Reached End of file */
            break;
        }
        memset(out_buf, 204, sizeof(out_buf));
        memset(in_buf, 204, sizeof(in_buf));
    }    
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
}
```

Here `cipher_params_t` is a struct:

```
typedef struct _cipher_params_t {
    unsigned char* key;
    unsigned char* iv;
    unsigned int encrypt;
    const EVP_CIPHER* cipher_type;
}cipher_params_t;
```

In `main()`, We set `key`,`IV` by generating random keys. `EVP_CIPHER` is set to `EVP_aes_128_cbc()`; Here is main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    FILE* f_input, * f_enc;


    cipher_params_t* params = (cipher_params_t*)malloc(sizeof(cipher_params_t));


    /* Key to use for encrpytion and decryption */
    unsigned char key[17] = "0123456789abcdef";

    /* Initialization Vector */
    unsigned char iv[17] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

    /* Generate cryptographically strong pseudo-random bytes for key and IV */
    //if (!RAND_bytes(key, sizeof(key)) || !RAND_bytes(iv, sizeof(iv))) {
    //    /* OpenSSL reports a failure, act accordingly */
    //    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: RAND_bytes error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    //    return errno;
    //}
    params->key = key;
    params->iv = iv;

    /* Indicate that we want to encrypt */
    params->encrypt = 1;

    /* Set the cipher type you want for encryption-decryption */
    params->cipher_type = EVP_aes_128_cbc();

    /* Open the input file for reading in binary ("rb" mode) */
    f_input = fopen("C:\\CMakeCache.txt", "rb");


    /* Open and truncate file to zero length or create ciphertext file for writing */
    f_enc = fopen("C:\\20161224_143119_DEC.txt", "wb");


    /* Encrypt the given file */
    file_encrypt_decrypt(params, f_input, f_enc);

    /* Encryption done, close the file descriptors */
    fclose(f_input);
    fclose(f_enc);

    /* Free the memory allocated to our structure */
    free(params);

    return 0;
}
```

This program works as expected and generates encrypted file, but when I decrypt using JAVA, file gets decrypted but with some junk characters. In java we used `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` and for decryption also we do the same, from file buffer we first read 4128 bytes then extract 16 bytes (for IV) then on remaining byte we perform `cipher.doFinal()`. This java program also performs decryption of file without any error but it gives some junk characters in decrypted file.

**Observations (while digging the issue):**

In decrypted file, after every 4096 bytes some junk characters are written (of exactly 16 bytes). If we implement encryption in java then file gets decrypted in java without junk chars. Same, If I implement decryption in c++ then no junk chars in output file.

Once again sorry for such long question, I really not getting what is happening? What process putting junk characters in decrypted file which was encrypted in c++?

Comment: Note: for testing purpose `IV` is hard coded, actual idea is to generate random IV for every 4096 bytes.

Comment: What is the purpose of encrypting the file in chunks of 4096 bytes ?

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen As I said for every 4096 bytes a new random IV will be generated for encryption, that's why I am encrypting file in 4096 chunk of bytes. (I know it is too bad ) Actually decryption logic is already written in that way in JAVA and I cannot change it. So to avail that service we have to encrypt data in that way.

Comment: Try to move the second `EVP_CipherInit_ex` call (the one where key and IV are set) into the while loop. It may be necessary to reinitialize the context, since each chunk corresponds to a complete encryption terminated with `EVP_CipherFinal`. The moving is necessary at the latest when a random (and thus different) IV is used for each chunk.

Comment: @Topaco Yes you are correct, moving `EVP_CipherInit_ex()` call inti the loop solves the issue. And this same is also described on opensll site as _After this function is called, the encryption operation is finished and no further calls to EVP_EncryptUpdate() should be made._

Comment: @Topaco, Please update as answer, and allow me to take a chance to appreciate you :)

Comment: Probably best to write an answer yourself and mark it accepted after two days. That way it is at least clear that the question has been answered. Of course, the reuse of the IV with the same key is inherently insecure, so your code doesn't make that much sense to me.